# How to retrieve the data source from a datagridview generated without a binding source C#?

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource

I have a datagridview in my code. And I've added data to the datagridview through my program results.(without a data/binding source)

i.e dataGridView1.Rows.Add("var1", "var2", "var3");

How can I bring back the displayed data as data source of that datagridview?

Comment: If you are wanting a `DataSource`, then… is there some reason you do not “create” a `DataSource` and use it in the grid. Then… instead of… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add("var1", "var2", "var3");` … you could do something like.. `dataTable.Rows.Add("var1", "var2", "var3");`… if the `DataSource` is a `DataTable` … OR… `bindingListOfMyClass.Add(new myClass(“var1”, “var2”, "var3”));` … if using a `BindingList<T>` .... Then you will have your `DataSource`.

Comment: Yes, I can use as dataTable.Rows.Add("var1", "var2", "var3"); and then make it as Datasource. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could write like.. dataTable.Rows.Add("var1", "var2", "var3");… for making data source